# TActionMainMenuBar, VCL-Styles and MDI buttons(Minimize, Close etc) not being styled.

Tags: delphi, mdi, delphi-xe3, vcl-styles

I'm trying to make TActionMainMenuBar display styled MDI buttons like a TMainMenu does.

[image: VCL Styles problem]

Any suggestions? I can't stop using MDI for this project.

Comment: You could always stop using VCL styles.......

Comment: MDI was spawned with the idea of a single parent window hosting multiple instances of the same class of "document", Frames allow you to do just that without the unnecessary hassle for the developer and the user.

Comment: Can you include a sample code to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @RRUZ , in IDE create new MDI application, add ActionManager & ActionMainMenuBar to main form, use Vcl Styles, run project and cascade new child form.

Comment: @RRUZ As Peter Vonča said. But you need to maximaze the child window.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, first **this is not a Vcl Styles bug**, this is a VCL bug. This issue appears even if the Vcl Styles Are disabled.

[image]

[image]

The issue is located in the `TCustomMDIMenuButton.Paint` method which uses the old [`DrawFrameControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162480%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WinAPi method to draw the caption buttons.

```
procedure TCustomMDIMenuButton.Paint;
begin
  DrawFrameControl(Canvas.Handle, ClientRect, DFC_CAPTION,
    MouseStyles[MouseInControl] or ButtonStyles[ButtonStyle] or
    PushStyles[FState = bsDown]);
end;
```

As workaround you can patch this method using a *detour* and then implementing a new paint method using the `StylesServices`.

Just add this unit to your project.

```
unit PatchMDIButtons;

interface

implementation

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  Winapi.Windows,
  Vcl.Themes,
  Vcl.Styles,
  Vcl.ActnMenus;

type
  TCustomMDIMenuButtonClass= class(TCustomMDIMenuButton);

  TJumpOfs = Integer;
  PPointer = ^Pointer;

  PXRedirCode = ^TXRedirCode;
  TXRedirCode = packed record
    Jump: Byte;
    Offset: TJumpOfs;
  end;

  PAbsoluteIndirectJmp = ^TAbsoluteIndirectJmp;
  TAbsoluteIndirectJmp = packed record
    OpCode: Word;
    Addr: PPointer;
  end;

var
  PaintMethodBackup   : TXRedirCode;

function GetActualAddr(Proc: Pointer): Pointer;
begin
  if Proc <> nil then
  begin
    if (Win32Platform = VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT) and (PAbsoluteIndirectJmp(Proc).OpCode = $25FF) then
      Result := PAbsoluteIndirectJmp(Proc).Addr^
    else
      Result := Proc;
  end
  else
    Result := nil;
end;

procedure HookProc(Proc, Dest: Pointer; var BackupCode: TXRedirCode);
var
  n: NativeUInt;
  Code: TXRedirCode;
begin
  Proc := GetActualAddr(Proc);
  Assert(Proc <> nil);
  if ReadProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess, Proc, @BackupCode, SizeOf(BackupCode), n) then
  begin
    Code.Jump := $E9;
    Code.Offset := PAnsiChar(Dest) - PAnsiChar(Proc) - SizeOf(Code);
    WriteProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess, Proc, @Code, SizeOf(Code), n);
  end;
end;

procedure UnhookProc(Proc: Pointer; var BackupCode: TXRedirCode);
var
  n: NativeUInt;
begin
  if (BackupCode.Jump <> 0) and (Proc <> nil) then
  begin
    Proc := GetActualAddr(Proc);
    Assert(Proc <> nil);
    WriteProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess, Proc, @BackupCode, SizeOf(BackupCode), n);
    BackupCode.Jump := 0;
  end;
end;


procedure PaintPatch(Self: TObject);
const
  ButtonStyles: array[TMDIButtonStyle] of TThemedWindow = (twMDIMinButtonNormal, twMDIRestoreButtonNormal, twMDICloseButtonNormal);
var
  LButton : TCustomMDIMenuButtonClass;
  LDetails: TThemedElementDetails;
begin
  LButton:=TCustomMDIMenuButtonClass(Self);
  LDetails := StyleServices.GetElementDetails(ButtonStyles[LButton.ButtonStyle]);
  StyleServices.DrawElement(LButton.Canvas.Handle, LDetails, LButton.ClientRect);
end;

procedure HookPaint;
begin
  HookProc(@TCustomMDIMenuButtonClass.Paint, @PaintPatch, PaintMethodBackup);
end;

procedure UnHookPaint;
begin
  UnhookProc(@TCustomMDIMenuButtonClass.Paint, PaintMethodBackup);
end;


initialization
 HookPaint;
finalization
 UnHookPaint;
end.
```

The result will be

[image]
[image]

Comment: You are welcome, don' forget report this issue to the QC site http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx