# How can I perform a fresh build of ALL of the built-in libraries that come pre-installed with Delphi 11.3 Alexandria?

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

I want to perform a fresh build of ALL of the built-in libraries that come pre-installed with Delphi 11.3 Alexandria.

I have noticed the `Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\source\rtl\buildrtl.bat` file that appears to build the RTL. Unfortunately, this `.bat` file assumes that you have access to the command line Delphi compiler, which does not come as part of Delphi Community Edition. Also, this is the only `.bat` build file that I can find for Delphi, and I want to perform a build for ALL of the built-in Delphi libraries which appear to be located in `Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\source` and are named as follows:

```
data
databinding
DataExplorer
DunitX
FlatBox2D
fmx
indy
Indy10
internet
Property Editors
rtl
soap
tethering
ToolsAPI
vcl
Visualizers
xml
```

Things I have tried so far:

1. I tried creating a single Delphi application, making a separate copy of the `Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\source` folder and placing it in my application's source code folder, adding this copy of the `source` folder to my project, and building the application. This did not work seemingly, because I was trying to compile too many files in a single application. When compiling this many files, the IDE-based compiler seems to fail. According to what I have read on the Internet, compiling this many files only works when you enable using `MSBuild.exe` to perform the build, which does not work for me since the Community Edition of Delphi does not allow you to use the Delphi command-line compiler, which `MSBuild.exe` relies on.
2. I tried creating individual Delphi applications per library, making a separate copy of the `Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\source\LIBRARY-NAME` folder and placing it in my application's source code folder, adding this copy of the `source\LIBRARY-NAME` folder to my project, and building the application. I am working my way through the libraries, but so far only the `databinding` and `FlatBox2D` libraries allow me to successfully build them this way. I am running into trouble in general because the Delphi libraries make a lot of references to files that reside in other folders. So, I am slowly adding those files as needed, but sometimes they don't exist, for example, some `.ICO` files (which I then comment out), some files containing certain Delphi classes (which is a bigger issue for me), etc.

Please note that:

1. I am using Delphi 11.3 Alexandria Community Edition.
2. I had all of the platforms installed, i.e. Windows, macOS, iOS, and Android when trying to build the libraries.
3. I failed to have all of the "Optional" items installed: TeeChart Standard, DUnit Unit Testing Frameworks, InterBase Express (IBX) Components, InterBase 2020 Developer Edition, Android SDK 25.2.5 - NDI r21, Eclipse Temurin OpenJDK 11 (Hotspot) JVM). I am installing them now, and will be trying to build the libraries again once they are installed.

Questions:

1. Is there an overall better way to approach what I am doing?
2. Is there an existing project (that I have been unable to find via Google) that provides a convenient way to build the built-in libraries? I have found a few webpages discussing how to do it manually (which I have tried to follow), but they are invariably incomplete, and are for versions of Delphi that are extremely old.
3. Do I need to use the Professional, Enterprise, or Architect editions of Delphi instead of the Community edition?
4. If I did use the Professional, Enterprise, or Architect editions of Delphi instead of the Community edition, would those editions come with additional built-in libraries that are not part of the Community Edition?

Comment: Can you explain the reason why you want to do an RTL recompile? I am asking because usually you are not supposed to do that.

Comment: @UweRaabe Nor should it be needed. OP didn't say "Why..."

Comment: Hesitating to make this an answer, but 1 = no, 2 = no, 3 = yes, 4 = yes

Comment: Best solution is to do none of this. This will take you no time to achieve your goals.

Comment: Maybe a XY problem here!? What's your real goal?

Comment: Following posts might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25555009/f2051-unit-s-was-compiled-with-a-different-version-of-s and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27537343/how-do-you-recompile-the-delphi-xe7-runtime

Answer (score 2):

First you need to understand that Delphi does ship with some source code that source code is not complete even if you have Architect edition of Delphi.

Second thing you need to understand is that the purpose of this source code is not for your to be compiling it by yourself but for you to better understand of how internals of some components and libraries work. Knowing this allows you to extend such code more easily.

The third thing you need to understand is that when you are compiling your application these source files are not being recompiled every time. Instead Delphi is linking bunch of precompiled units and packages that you can find in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\lib` folder and its subfolders. This is what allows Delphi to build a final application so quickly since it is basically just linking pars of already compiled code unlike most other programming languages that require compiling each unit in your project each time. Drawback is that final compiled and linked code is not as optimized as in some other programming languages.

And finally some of these units or packages might require custom compilation parameters in order to compile properly. But Embarcadero does not share such information with general public.

---

Any way in most cases there is no reason for you to ever compile any of these files yourself. Only reason where you might want to recompile some of these files is if there is some bug in Embarcadero code and you cant wait for next release for it to be fixed.